# How to create calculated Fields in Partial Classes - WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, inotifypropertychanged, partial-classes, calculated-columns

I am trying to use the calculated columns to display in my grid.

I have a partial class automatically generated by EF code generator with three properties: and i am trying to creating another partial class and add calculated field there for e.g.

```
Public partial class Employee
{
public decimal? totalSalary
{
get

{
return salary*wagerate+bonus;
}
}
}
```

It works fine for the first time but does not work when the salary/bonus/hours are changed. I am using these fields inside a grid

Here is my code generated by EF entity generator

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Employees.Contract
{
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Department))]
[KnownType(typeof(PropertyType))]
public partial class Employee: IObjectWithChangeTracker, INotifyPropertyChanged,IDataErrorInfo
{

    [NonSerialized]
    private CLOS.Contract.Validation.DataErrorInfoSupport dataErrorInfoSupport;

    public Employee()
    {            
        dataErrorInfoSupport = new CLOS.Contract.Validation.DataErrorInfoSupport(this);
        Init();
    }

    partial void Init();

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return dataErrorInfoSupport.Error; } }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string memberName] { get { return dataErrorInfoSupport[memberName]; } }

    #region Primitive Properties


    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> Salary
    {
        get { return _salary; }
        set
        {
            if (_salary != value)
            {
                _salary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Salary");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _salary;

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> WageRate
    {
        get { return _wageRate; }
        set
        {
            if (_wageRate != value)
            {
                _wageRate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("WageRate");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _wageRate;

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> Bonus
    {
        get { return _bonus; }
        set
        {
            if (_bonus != value)
            {
                _bonus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Bonus");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _bonus;

    #endregion
    #region Navigation Properties

    [DataMember]
    public Department Department
    {
        get { return _department; }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_department, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _department;
                _department = value;
                OnNavigationPropertyChanged("Department");
            }
        }
    }
    private Borrower _department;

    [DataMember]
    public PropertyType PropertyType
    {
        get { return _propertyType; }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_propertyType, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _propertyType;
                _propertyType = value;

                OnNavigationPropertyChanged("PropertyType");
            }
        }
    }
    private PropertyType _propertyType;

    #endregion
    #region ChangeTracking

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Added && ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Deleted)
        {
            ChangeTracker.State = ObjectState.Modified;
        }
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnNavigationPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged{ add { _propertyChanged += value; } remove { _propertyChanged -= value; } }
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
    private ObjectChangeTracker _changeTracker;

    [DataMember]
    public ObjectChangeTracker ChangeTracker
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changeTracker == null)
            {
                _changeTracker = new ObjectChangeTracker();
                _changeTracker.ObjectStateChanging += HandleObjectStateChanging;
            }
            return _changeTracker;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_changeTracker != null)
            {
                _changeTracker.ObjectStateChanging -= HandleObjectStateChanging;
            }
            _changeTracker = value;
            if(_changeTracker != null)
            {
                _changeTracker.ObjectStateChanging += HandleObjectStateChanging;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleObjectStateChanging(object sender, ObjectStateChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewState == ObjectState.Deleted)
        {
            ClearNavigationProperties();
        }
    }

    protected bool IsDeserializing { get; private set; }

    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        IsDeserializing = true;
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        dataErrorInfoSupport = new CLOS.Contract.Validation.DataErrorInfoSupport(this);
        IsDeserializing = false;
        ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected virtual void ClearNavigationProperties()
    {
        Department = null;
        PropertyType = null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

It also works if i put `OnPropertyChanged("Salary")` in Hours,Wage,Overtime Property in EF Generated class (which is not a good idea) because if the class gets regenerated , my code will be wiped out

Any help is appreciated. (Sorry for the formatting , this is my first question)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the partial class use the partial Init method to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event and when either the salary, wagerate or bonus property changes notify clients of the change of the totalSalary.

**This way you do not need to modify the generated code. (that is why the Init method is partial).**

```
public partial class Employee
{

    partial void Init()
    {
        _propertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
    }

    void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.PropertyName == "salary" ||
           args.PropertyName == "wagerate" ||
           args.PropertyName == "bonus")
         {
             OnPropertyChanged("totalSalary");
         }
    }

    public decimal? totalSalary
    {
        get
        {
            return salary * wagerate + bonus;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Erno, Thanks for your reply but PropertyChangedHandler does not get executed when the value is changed for Salary Wagerate or bonus... It goes to OnProperyChanged event in EF generate class but does not come to PropertyChangedHandler method. I guess it is removing the handler somewhere in between and by the way I could not use PropertyChanged+=  I had to use _propertyChanged+= which i suppose should be same thing

Comment: You are correct about the `_propertyChanged` (I adjusted my answer). You could try and step through the code/debug and see what is going on.

Comment: It Comes to this line of code and then just dies  and does not invoke the handler           protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Added && ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Deleted)
        {
            ChangeTracker.State = ObjectState.Modified;
        }
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

Comment: That is not ONE line. Check all the variables: is ChangeTracker null? What value is State, etc. etc.

Comment: What i meant to say that it invokes this line of code  _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)) but does not go to the handler after that..

Comment: I am sorry but I can't debug this for you. Check if the Init function is called in time, check if the event is cleared anywhere.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this functionality without modifying the EF generated class

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5440166/563088 it uses a different event and doesn't require the Init method

Comment: It uses the same thing what you suggested, I can also call OnPropertyChanged in setters of each of the property the problem is i dont want to modify the EF generated class...

Answer (score 0):

this is why MVVM is a popular design pattern, if you wrap your Employee (a Model) in a new class (a ViewModel), it will be easier to customise before you hand it to the grid (the View).

However, a hacky way to get your current code working would be to attach to the current PropertyChanged event in your partial class and call `OnPropertyChanged("Salary")` if the current property name matches one of the dependent properties (watch out for recursion!)